# Regular Expression with VS2010 C++ / Boost

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, boost, boost-regex

I am trying to take a string in C++ and find the project name and path contained inside. The string has the format:

```
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "OpenGL01", "OpenGL01\OpenGL01.vcxproj", "{65E58BFD-4339-44BA-BA9B-B2B8A5AC1FE1}"
```

And the regular expression is:

```
boost::regex expression("(Project\(\"\{.*\}\"\)) ?= ?(\".*\"), ?(\".*\"), ?(\"\{.*\}\")");
```

But this line generate a exception error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x7512d36f in kmCompile2010.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: `boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::regex_error> >` at memory location 0x004ce13c..

This is the complete function:

```
BOOL CSlnFile::ReadProjectsSolution()
{
    CString sLine;
    boost::regex expression("(Project\(\"\{.*\}\"\)) ?= ?(\".*\"), ?(\".*\"), ?(\"\{.*\}\")");

    BOOL bCheck = FALSE;

    SeekToBegin();

    while(ReadString(sLine) && !bCheck) {   
        // CString to char*
        CT2A temp(sLine);           // uses LPCTSTR conversion operator for CString and CT2A constructor
        const char* pszA = temp;    // uses LPSTR conversion operator for CT2A
        std::string strA(pszA);     // uses std::string constructor

        boost::smatch what;

        if (regex_match(strA, what, expression, boost::match_extra)) {
            // TODO
        }
    }

    return bCheck;
}
```

I not found my mistake. Can you help me?

Comment: You need to double-escape everything but the quotes: `boost::regex expression("(Project\\(\"\\{.*\\}\"\\)) ?= ?(\".*\"), ?(\".*\"), ?(\"\\{.*\\}\")");`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try the the following regex in boost::regex, it works in perl:

```
\{([^}]+)\}"[^"]*"([^"]+)", "([^"]+)", "\{([^}]+)
```

I tried it on the command line:

```
echo 'Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "OpenGL01", "OpenGL01\OpenGL01.vcxproj", "{65E58BFD-4339-44BA-BA9B-B2B8A5AC1FE1}"' | perl -ne 'my ($a, $b, $c, $d) = /\{([^}]+)\}"[^"]*"([^"]+)", "([^"]+)", "\{([^}]+)/; print "$a, $b, $c, $d"'
```